# Erro ao tentar fazer push em um commit

Tags: git

Eu sou novo no git através do terminal, estou enfrentando o seguinte problema e não consigo forçar. Alguém sabe como posso proceder para corrigir este erro?

```
$ git push

stdin: is not a tty
Counting objects: 4, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
Writing objects: 100% (4/4), 381 bytes | 381.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 4 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0)
To 
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (Working directory has unstaged changes)
error: failed to push some refs to '
```

Comment: Se você fizer um git status, o que ele retorna?

Comment: Ele retorna :     $ git status
No ramo master
Seu ramo está à frente de 'origin/master' por 1 submissão.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

nothing to commit, working tree clean

Comment: O repositório no servidor remoto é `bare`? Ou contém os arquivos propriamente ditos? Parece-me que alguém modificou no servidor que você está conectando algum arquivo e deixou ele sem elencar

Comment: E isso ai mesmo e eu não sei como fazer isso ja que não tenho acesso a serve so ao clone.